# Lombok: access object whose custom builder is generated from custom builder

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 `@Entity` classes - `User` and `UserProfile`. I have created a `one to one` mapping between them using `Hibernate`. Here is the sample code:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(
                            name = "uuid_gen_strategy_class",
                            value = "org.hibernate.id.uuid.CustomVersionOneStrategy"
                    )
            }
    )
    @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID userId;

    @OneToOne(
            mappedBy = "user",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            optional = false
    )
    private UserProfile profile;

    static class UserBuilder {

        private User user;

        public UserBuilder profile(UserProfile profile) {
            if (Objects.isNull(profile)) {
                if (!Objects.isNull(this.user.profile)) {
                    this.user.profile.setUser(null);
                }
            } else {
                profile.setUser(user);
            }
            this.user.profile = profile;
            return this;
        }
    }
```

`UserProfile` POJO is defined as:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor

@Entity
public class UserProfile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator",
            parameters = {
                    @Parameter(
                            name = "uuid_gen_strategy_class",
                            value = "org.hibernate.id.uuid.CustomVersionOneStrategy"
                    )
            }
    )
    @Column(columnDefinition = "CHAR(36)")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID userId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private User user;
}
```

Now when I am trying to use the builder for `User`, I get an error that the existing fields are not found. The reason why I needed this custom builder is because i would like to create relationship between `User` and `UserProfile` in one place and not have to worry about setting this information everywhere the object is being created.
How do i fix this issue or is there a better way to achieve what i am trying to do here?

**Updated**

---

Here is the sample code that is giving the error:
```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RegisterUserRequestToUserMapper {

```
private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public User map(RegisterUserRequest request) {
    return User.builder()
            .email(request.getEmail())
            .password(passwordEncoder.encode(request.getPassword()))
            .roles(Set.of(Entitlement.USER))
            .profile(
                    UserProfile.builder()
                            .firstName(request.getFirstName())
                            .lastName(request.getLastName())
                            .build()
            )
            .build();
}
```

}

```
The line that says `.email(...)`  is giving above error.
```

Comment: Can you please provide the example code snippet you would like to use in this case which is failing?

Comment: @Iprakashv I have updated the code with the function call.

Comment: that seems correct: *your `User`* (nor `UserProfile`) has no `email` ... probably you want another (package) `User`!?;) (-> conflicting import! ..seeing `@Component` and `passwordEncoder`, you probably need [`org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html)??)

Comment: @xerx593 it has. it was just omitted from the question for brevity. There is no conflicting imports as well. Again, the question is just a minimum verifiable sample.